# Add /usr/local/include to Xcode default include search path

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, glfw, glad

Xcode seems to not be able to find the header files on /usr/local/include by default: [file not found error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BTa9.png).

I know it can be fixed by adding the path in the target -> Build Settings -> Header Search Paths:
[workaround](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXXhp.png).

Is it possible to let Xcode treat /usr/local/include as a system header search path? So it can find the headers without adding them to: target -> Build Settings -> Header Search Paths.

Comment: What does `clang++ -E -v -x c++ /dev/null` show, from Terminal.app?  You should have `/usr/local/include` already in your include search path.

Comment: #include <...> search starts here: /usr/local/include. It does show in clang's search list but Xcode seems to fail looking for the folder anyway.

Comment: XCode 12.0.5 and i can confirm that /usr/local/include is listed with the above clang++ command line but it does not use it